# How to import a list from a class from a file?

Tags: python

I need to import a list (list1, list2, list3) which is in a class in another file. there are more classes and I need to import and use the lists in the classes in file2 to file1.

**file 1:**

```
from file2 import Quiz1
from file2 import Quiz2

print(Quiz1.list1)  # trying to print the list from quiz1 but it doesn't work
print(Quiz1.list2)
print(Quiz1.list3)

print(Quiz2.list1)

...
```

**file 2:**

```
class Quiz1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list1 = []   # list1 
        self.list2 = []
        self.list3 = []

        self.list1.append('Select the European City: ')
        self.list2.extend(['Abu Dhabi', 'Washington DC', 'New York', 'Rome'])
        self.list3.append(4)

 class Quiz2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list1 = []
        self.list2 = []
        self.list3 = []

        self.list1.append('Select the city which is not located in America: ')
        self.list2.extend(['Denver', 'Washington DC', 'San Francisco', 'Berlin'])
        self.list3.append(4)

 class Quiz3:
     def __init__(self):
        self.list1 = []
 ...
```

Comment: The lists are ***instance*** attributes, not ***class*** attributes. You need to create an instance to access its lists i.e. `Quiz2().list1`

Comment: is there a way I can check how many classes are there in that file?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can do something with `inspect`, but you have the wrong approach. There should be only one class `Quiz` and you should have multiple instances of this class with different values for the attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it that way

```
from file2 import Quiz1
quiz1 = Quiz1()
print(quiz1.list1)
```

or

```
from file2 import Quiz1
print(Quiz1().list1)
```